# How to remove duplicates from a vector of pair<int, Object>

Tags: c++

This is what I am trying right now. I made a comparison function:

```
bool compare(const std::pair<int, Object>& left, const std::pair<int, Object>& right)
{
    return (left.second.name == right.second.name) && (left.second.time == right.second.time) && 
        (left.second.value == right.second.value);
}
```

After I add an element I call `std::unique` to filter duplicates:

```
data.push_back(std::make_pair(index, obj));
data.erase(std::unique(data.begin(), data.end(), compare), data.end());
```

But it seems that this doesn't work. And I don't know what the problem is.
From my understanding `std::unique` should use the `compare` predicate.

How should I update my code to make this work ?
I am using C++03.

edit:

I have tried to sort it too, but still doens't work.

```
bool compare2(const std::pair<int, Object>& left, const std::pair<int, Object>& right)
{
    return (left.second.time< right.second.time);
}

std::sort(simulatedLatchData.begin(), simulatedLatchData.end(), compare2);
```

Comment: Is the vector sorted?

Comment: No, I haven't sort it.

Comment: as Nathan noted, it works only on sorted sequences.

Comment: `std::unique` requires the range to be sorted

Comment: Oh, I uderstand, ok, let me try it out.

Comment: Well, technically, `std::unique` does not require the range to be sorted. But it will only remove adjacent duplicates. So if your goal to remove all duplicates, then you need duplicates to be grouped together. And the best way to do that, is to sort.

Comment: I try to sort vector, still doesn't work. I have updated my question with code.

Comment: Your only sorting by `time`.  You need to sort by all the members as `compare` checks all of them.

Comment: This smells bad. Why do you have such `pair<int,Object>`s? Is the `first` part some sort of index? Why don't you compare the `int` too? Also, why don't you simply *avoid* to `push_back()` an element that duplicates one already contained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) requires the range passed to it to have all the duplicate elements next to one another in order to work.

You can use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) on the range before you a call `unique` to achieve that as sorting automatically groups duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting and filtering is nice, but since you *never* want any duplicate, why not use `std::set`?
And while we're at it, these pairs look suspiciously like key-values, so how about `std::map`?

Comment: Exactly my thoughts too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep only unique objects, then use an appropriate container type, such as a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (or [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)). For example

```
bool operator<(object const&, object const&); 

std::set<object> data;
object obj = new_object(/*...*/);
data.insert(obj);    // will only insert if unique
```